# facebook connect ssl issue

Tags: ssl, facebook, fbconnect

I have bought a ssl certificate to enable ssl encription on my website.
I have fbconnect button to login with my site.
I'm sure that ssl encription is working.
The problem is that when I click the fbconnect button I don't receive response from facebook.
Is there some setting that I need to change?
Thank you.

M.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a related issue with this one : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/182705755149358?browse=search_4ec3beea8af119f67451579

Comment: not my case unfortunately. I don't see timeout in the log and when I go on port 80 on my website fbconnect works well.

Comment: Well I have no idea... Have you double check your app configuration (FB side)?